# wget.download raises indexerror when trying to download image

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, wget, index-error

I have been trying **wget** recently instead of requests and it is pretty straightforward and easy to use but I have been having a problem with a specific link.

When I try to download a png image from wikipedia **for some reason wget.download keeps raising an IndexError when trying to write to the file** this error in specific:

```
    wget.download(url, f"C:/Users/Family/Pictures/downloads/{name}")
  File "C:\Users\Family\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\wget.py", line 527, in download
    filename = detect_filename(url, out, headers)
  File "C:\Users\Family\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\wget.py", line 486, in detect_filename
    names["headers"] = filename_from_headers(headers) or ''
  File "C:\Users\Family\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\wget.py", line 258, in filename_from_headers
    name = fnames[0].split('=')[1].strip(' \t"')
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I tried setting a specific filename but it still didn't work. When I use wget in my cmd it does not seem to have a problem with the url, so how can I fix this?

```
import wget


# This is the link to the image
url = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b6/Image_created_with_a_mobile_phone.png/1200px-Image_created_with_a_mobile_phone.png"

# It does not seem to have a problem detecting the filename
name = wget.detect_filename(url)

# I tried to set a specific filename but I still got the error with ot whout it
wget.download(url, f"C:/Users/Family/Pictures/downloads/{name}")
```

Comment: it is clear to me that there is a list and Your index is out of that list, can You provide more code? that includes `fnames` and how it is created

Comment: @Matiiss I have not defined fname, what you see above is my full python script. Wget itself defines fname not me

Comment: when You set a specific filename You should also add the extension (try .png in this case) and don't use the `.detect_filename(url)` just three lines of code `import wget`, `url = ...` and `wget.download(url, f"C:/Users/Family/Pictures/downloads/test.png")` try this and if that does not work I have no idea

Comment: @Matiiss I know that you should mention the extension as well and I tried that but still got the same error

Comment: I have no idea then, I can only suggest using requests, here is the tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tb8gHvYlCFs

Answer (score 0):

I have the same case as you do.
When I did some research of the reply header,
in my case if the URL header does not contain **'content-disposition': 'attachment; filename="xxx"'**, it will throw this error, hope this help.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32575896)